# How to create a new column based off logic related to rows above/below

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table similar to this:

```
|ID|      |Error|              |Subject|             |Note|
==============================================================
|1    |Start Date Required    |Flag Flip        |Flipped per cust|

|1    |Start Date Required    |Date             |Start Date and End Date N.A.

|1    |End Date Required      |Flag Flip        |Flipped per cust

|1    |End Date Required      |Date             |Start Date and End Date N.A.

|8    |Description Required   |Date             |Date

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Factor           |Factor is N.A

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Factor Update    |Factor is N.A.

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Sink             |Not Sinkable
```

I am trying to create another column named 'STATUS'.
I can have multiple notes per ID and sometimes they are not related to the error.
That is why you see that for ID 1, there are only 2 errors, but 4 columns because there is a 'flag flip' note also attached to this ID.
For every 'ERROR', it will repeat each note attached to an ID.

We are only concerned with the SUBJECT/NOTE that is related to the ERROR.
If the ID is the same, and ONE of the NOTE column pertains to the ERROR column then it can have a status of 'CLEAR'. 
If there is no Note related to the error, then it must have a status of 'Review'

**The Table I would like to have as a result of this logic**

```
|ID|      |Error|              |Subject|             |Note|                    |STATUS|
=======================================================================================
|1    |Start Date Required    |Flag Flip        |Flipped per cust|              |Clear|

|1    |Start Date Required    |Date             |Start Date and End Date N.A.   |Clear|

|1    |End Date Required      |Flag Flip        |Flipped per cust               |Clear|

|1    |End Date Required      |Date             |Start Date and End Date N.A.   |Clear|

|8    |Description Required   |Date             |Date                           |Review|

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Factor           |Factor is N.A                  |Clear|

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Factor Update    |Factor is N.A.                 |Clear|

|4    |Sink Flag not set      |Sink             |Not Sinkable                   |Clear|
```

If row above or below has the same ID, and ERROR column has NOTE associated to it, then CLEAR. If no note related to error (per id) then REVIEW.

For Example, because ID 1 has a start date/end date error, and the NOTE is pertaining to the start date/end date being N.A then it can have a status of CLEAR for ALL 4 rows with ID 1

Because ID 8 has an ERROR of 'Description Required', but the NOTE has to do with a DATE, then it must be reviewed because there is no note about description.

Because ID 4 has a Sink Flag error, and there is one row with a SINK subject/note then it can have a status of CLEAR for all 3 rows

I am not sure how to write this logic. I have the logic for each row separately, but I don't know how to have them be related by ID so that if one row with the same ID has a note related to the error, then all rows with that ID can be cleared. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: what tell you what is the row before current one? you have an id or date field?

Comment: isnt clear when a note is an error or clear the error.

Comment: *" If there is no Note related to the error"* What does this mean? All your sample data has a populated `note` column so how do you know whether the `note` relates to the `error`? Is it simply when `note != subject`? Or something more sophisticated? Unfortunately, it's unlikely anybody will be able to help until you explain the logic.

Comment: "if there is no NOTE related to the ERROR" means that if the error has a note with info regarding the error then it can be cleared. Since start date error has a note about the start date it can be cleared.

Comment: If an ID has an error, it has to have a note related to that error. In this example, ID 4 has a Sink flag error AND has a note stating its not sinkable, aka the note is related to the error and can be cleared. Another example: Since ID 1 has a start date error, one of the notes has to have information on the start date otherwise it cant be cleared.

Comment: Yes but how you know a note is related without reaiding it? SQL doesnt have an AI engine yet.

Comment: @Amachiner so you mean like `CASE WHEN error LIKE '%Date Required' AND Note LIKE '%'||REPLACE(error, ' Required', '%') THEN 'Clear' ELSE 'Error' END` ? => It tests if error ends with "date required" and the note mentions either "start date" or "end date" (depending on what the error was).. i.e. it's a lot of complex rules - how can we know them all?!

Comment: exactly! That is what I have for logic in my query that im working on right now. I just dont know how to apply it to multiple rows (if theres more than one row per ID). How would I use that logic to apply it to any other row with the same ID though?

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so we've managed to get to a place where we can build some intelligence into the query so it knows how to deal with some errors.. and we can build from there

Here's a first pass query based on what we know:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  CASE 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Date Required' AND Note LIKE '%'||REPLACE(error, ' Required', '%') THEN 'Clear' 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Sink%' and note LIKE '%sink%' THEN 'Clear'
    ELSE 'Review' 
  END as Status
FROM
  table
```

It would turn SOME of the rows to Clear, but most to review. We DOn't mind this thought because yu seem to be saying that so long as any single row for a given ID is 'Clear' they can all be clear. In this case I will utilize the fact that alphabetically 'Clear' is before 'Review', so if we group by ID and ask for the MIN status, if anything is Clear, they all get a Clear:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  MIN(CASE 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Date Required' AND Note LIKE '%'||REPLACE(error, ' Required', '%') THEN 'Clear' 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Sink%' and note LIKE '%sink%' THEN 'Clear'
    ELSE 'Review' 
  END) as Status
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  ID
```

Now all we need to do to apply this per-id determination is to make it a subquery and join it back to the data:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 
  ID, 
  MIN(CASE 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Date Required' AND Note LIKE '%'||REPLACE(error, ' Required', '%') THEN 'Clear' 
    WHEN error LIKE '%Sink%' and note LIKE '%sink%' THEN 'Clear'
    ELSE 'Review' 
  END) as Status
 FROM
  table
 GROUP BY 
  ID
) determine
INNER JOIN
table t
ON 
  t.ID = determine.ID
```